# How to put multiple ip on pg_hba.conf

Tags: postgresql

I need do allow two ip to connect on my database: 127.0.0.1 and 10.10.10.1.

I am trying use: `host   all   all   127.0.0.1/32,10.10.10.1   md5` but it not works.

How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put them on separate lines:

---

```
host   all   all   127.0.0.1/32   md5
host   all   all   10.10.10.1/32  md5
```

Comment: this permits to connect the two ip on same time?

Comment: It allows **both** of them to connect.

Comment: didn't work for me, postgresql service on Windows didn't even restart